# Sql server select group by order by different field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table:

```
Id    Date        color
------------------------- 
 1    23/04/2013  red
 2    23/04/2013  white
 3    23/04/2013  yellow
 4    23/04/2013  red
 5    23/04/2013  orange
 6    23/04/2013  blue
 7    23/04/2013  yellow
 8    23/04/2013  red
```

I group by color and order by total and color:

```
Select top 5 color, count(color) as total from table where Date<=getdate() group by color order by total desc, color asc
```

So until herer, all is ok.

Now, I would want the same, but NOT ordering by color. I want to order by total, and then, by date. But I don't want to group by date.

Comment: Yes, It is enough for me. How do I accept or vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [Date] DATETIME
    , color NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([Date], color)
VALUES 
    ('20130423',  'red'),
    ('20130422',  'white'),
    ('20130423',  'yellow'),
    ('20130423',  'red'),
    ('20130425',  'orange'),
    ('20130423',  'blue'),
    ('20130423',  'yellow'),
    ('20130423',  'red')

SELECT TOP 5 color, total = COUNT(color)  
FROM @temp 
WHERE [Date] <= GETDATE() 
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY total DESC, MAX([Date])
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know SQL Server allowed aliases in the `order by` clause

Comment: You're welcome @onbermejo. In case this solution fully suits you, I would be glad if you could confirm it.